# Trying to load an image inside a assets/img folder in a v-for, but the images does not load

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to load the images in the assets/img folder in my vue3 project using a v-for inside a div, but they are not loading, just display my alt.
So, I have a vue component what will display a title and a paragraph and also a image. The images are in the assets/img folder, I'm getting the path of the image with a store that I created. When I try to just put the path of the image like this: `src="../assets/img/img2.jpg"` the images renders.

Here is 1 of my state in the store.js:

```
content: [
            {
                headline: 'Teste',
                paragraph: 'this is a paragraph',
                img: '@/assets/img/img.jpg'
            },]
```

Here is my template using the v-for:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      class="slider"
      v-for="item, i in content"
      :key='i'
    >
      <h1>{{item.headline}}</h1>
      <p>{{item.paragraph}}</p>
      <img
        :src="item.img"
        alt="test"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

My setup:

```
 setup () {
    const store = useStore()
    const content = store.getters.getContent

    return { content }

  }
```

I tryed to use `:src="require(item.img)"` but i got a webpack error by doing this:

*`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/img/img.jpg'     webpackEmptyContext components sync:2`*

Also tryed to point the folder of the images in the src, :src="@/assets/img + item.img", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met this question before.
Maybe the following code could help you.

```
// create a function in util.js
export const getSrc = ( name ) => {
   
  const path = `/src/assets/img/${name}`
  
  const modules = import.meta.globEager('/src/assets/img/*.jpg')

  return modules[path].default
}

// use getSrc in someItem.vue
import { getSrc } from '@/util/util.js'

content: [
   {
     headline: 'Teste',
     paragraph: 'this is a paragraph',
     img: getSrc('img.jpg')
   }
]
```

Comment: It didin't work becuse I think i need to install a module to use that globEager. But from the part of the path give me a hint to use `:src=require(@/assets/img/${item.img})` and them it worked!! Thank you!

Comment: thanks for your feedback. i forgot to tell you my env is vue3+vite. i guess your env is vue3+webpack, so globEager did not work. next time i will be more careful.

Comment: Oh sure! I have to study more about configs, but I will look for vite. I'm using the basic preset of vue cli. Thanks Yang! You help so much!